# How to exclude some resources from copy while building

Tags: objective-c, xcode, configuration

XCode is copying referenced folders like this:

```
CpResource /.../Resources /...ProductName.app/Resources
cd "/.../Resources"
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -resolve-src-symlinks /.../Resources /.../ProductName.app
```

What I need to do is exclude the subfolder of the Resources folder. Is this possible somehow? Is there any configuration flag for such thing?

Answer (score 0):

I had a situation where I needed a certain resource file to be present in Debug builds but not in Release  builds so I inserted a custom build rule to delete the file in the Release builds.

Maybe you could delete the subfolders after the copy. This would only work, I guess, if you knew the names of the sub-folders.

Sorta hacky but hey, it worked, maybe it would for you.